# Can you check my proof of suitable values of $a$ for this function $f_a$?

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification

I tried to solve the following :

Let 
$$ f_a (x) = 
\begin{cases}
x^a & x \ge 0 \\
0 & x < 0
\end{cases}$$

(a) For which values of $a$ is $f$ continuous at zero?

(b) For which values of $a$ is $f$ differentiable at $0$? In this case, is the derivative continuous?

(c) For which values of $a$ is $f$ twice differentiable?

Please, could someone check my answers? Thanks in advance.

(a) Claim: $f$ is continuous at $0$ for all $a > 0$.

Proof: Let $a >0$ and $\varepsilon> 0$. Let $\delta = \varepsilon^{1 \over a}$. Then $|f(x) - f(0)| = |x^a| < \varepsilon$. \

(b) Claim; $f$ is differentiable at $0$ if $a > 1$.

Proof: $$ \lim_{x \to 0} {f(x) - f(0) \over x} = \lim_{x\to 0} {x^a \over x} = 0$$

(c) Claim:  If $a > 2$.

Proof: The only point where there could be a problem is $0$. The derivative of $f$ for $x>0$ equals $f'(x) = a x^{a-1}$. Then $f''$ exists if and only if the following limit exists:
$$ \lim_{x \to 0} {f'(x) - f'(0) \over x}  = \lim_{x \to 0} {a x^{a-1} \over x}  $$
This limit is zero if $a>2$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First point: you must also prove that $f$ is not continous at zero for $a\leq 0$ before you can claim that you answered point ($a$). EDIT: same goes for points $c$ and $d$.

Second point:
Your proof of ($b$)  is slighlty misleading. When you send $x$ towards $0$, you cannot replace $f(x)$ with $x^a$, since for $x<0$, this does not hold.

Basically, what you calculated in places when you wrote LIMITS are actually only right-limits (a limit where $x$ falls towards a certain value). A function is differentiable in a point if the right and left limits of $\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}$ coincide.

Comment: Thank you. And did I find the correct values for $a$?

Comment: Yes. None of your proofs is completely off target. There is just one more point I noticed, which I am adding to my answer.

Comment: Regarding your first point, I'm not 100% clear. If $a<0$ the map $f_a$ is not defined on all of $\mathbb R$. Although not explicitly specified, wouldn't it be natural to assume that the resulting $f_a$ must be defined on all of $\mathbb R$?

Comment: Well, that's one thing you have to write. See, the claim "$f_a$ has property $P$ for $a>0$" is really saying two things: $f_a$ has this property, if $a>0$, and $f_a$ does NOT have this property if $a\leq 0$. Therefore, for $a\leq0$, you must be able to show why $f_a$ is not continuous at $0$. The fact that $f_a$ is not defined at $0$ is indeed the reason, but is must be stated!

Comment: Great, I think I get it, thank you for your guidance! Thanks to you I just noticed a mistake: in b it is probably also okay to have $a=1$ so it should be $a \ge 1$ but I will have to work it out in detail now.

Comment: Nope, $a=1$ doesn't work.

Comment: No! $f_a$ is NOT differentiable at $0$ for $a=1$! Since you have a left limit of $1$ and right limit of $0$, the derivative at $0$ does NOT exist! That's what I was talking about when I said that $f_a(x)$ does NOT equal $x^{a}$ around zero!

Comment: I found a better condition for (a) too: if $a$ is not $\ge 1$ then $f$ is not a map into $\mathbb R$ but a map into $\mathbb C$ so already in (a) it must be that $a \ge 1$.

Comment: This is not really a good way of thinking. See, $f$ is by definition a function from $\mathbb R$ to $\mathbb R$. If $a<0$, then it is, as you rightly figured out, not well defined at $0$, but for $0<a<1$, $f_a$ is a well defined real function. See, for example, $a=1/2$, when $f_a$ becomes $\sqrt x$ for all $x\geq 0$. This is entirely well defined for $x>0$, while for $x<0$, $f_a$ is $0$ by definition.

Comment: Oops, you're right of course. I forgot it's $0$ on the negative numbers!